# Problema para crear un usuario sftp con restricción a una ruta

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, sftp

Estoy creando un usuario sftp en Ubuntu, que está en una máquina virtual virtualbox de Oracle.

Quiero acceder a una ruta específica para transferir archivos de mi web sin necesidad de conectarme a la máquina virtual ni al control remoto. Para eso quiero usar un usuario sftp y luego conectarme a el desde mi equipo windows, usando Filezilla.

Aquí mi configruación:

usuario: prueba
contraseña: prueba
grupo de usuarios: prueba

directorio al que tiene que acceder únicamente: var/www/sftp/prueba/

Permisos establecidos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fichero sshd_config: (he visto que tengo que añadir estas últimas líneas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error que se produce en filezilla:

```
Comando:    open "prueba@localhost" 22
Comando:    Confiar en nueva clave de host: Una vez
Comando:    Pass: ******
Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
Error:  No se pudo conectar al servidor
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es eso de que te conectas a `localhost`? ¿No deberías poner ahí la IP de la máquina Ubuntu? ¿O tienes configurada su red en modo NAT y has redireccionado el puerto 22 de WIndows al 22 de Ubuntu?  En ese caso, ¿no te ha dado problemas el cortafuegos de windows al tratar de redireccionar el puerto 22?

Comment: Al margen de lo que te pregunto en mi anterior comentario, suponiendo que el problema de IP y puerto esté correcto y para diagnosticar otros posibles problemas,  descargate `psftp.exe` [de aqui](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) y ejecutarlo desde una terminal de comandos windows con la siguiente sintaxis: `psftp -v usuario@ip-sevidor -P puerto` Con la opción `-v` te va detallando los pasos del protocolo que va dando y podrás ver en cuál falla.

Comment: Nada es que puse localhost por ocultar mi ip interna (manías)... jajajaja. La máquina está configurada con adaptador puente.

Comment: @abulafia he probado psftp y tras enviar la password me devuelve: Access granted / Opening session as main channel / Network error: Software caused connection abort / Fatal: Network error: Software caused connection abort

Comment: Parece que el servidor cierra la conexión después de aceptarle. Posiblemente está relacionado con eso que has puesto de `ForceCommand`, si el comando en cuestión no lo encuentra. Mira a ver en los logs del servidor (syslog, auth.log)

Comment: [Esto](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-sftp-only-user-accounts-on-ubuntu-14) o [esto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-16-04) puede ser util. Aparentemente lo estás haciendo bien...

Comment: @abulafia he probado el primer link, y haciéndolo tal cual, no he tenido problemas. El problema surge cuando quiero que el directorio al que acceda al usuario es /var/ww/ y no /home/uploads/